# How to consume SOAP services in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

From past few days I've been trying to consume SOAP services in xamarin.Since SOAP cant be added to PCL , I'm directly adding it xamarin.android and xamarin.iOS project but relevant option is not appearing. I've also looked into Xamarin tutorials but it didnt helped me.
Can anybody explain how to consume the SOAP services in xamarin.android and xamarin.iOS.?

Comment: Xamarin has a few articles concerning this, along with sample code  @ http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/ , http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/web-services/ , etc....

Comment: I have gone through the articles but didnt found much of help.May be video explaining anything about this really helps.I'm using visual studio 2015 along with xamarin.android

Comment: Now I'm getting Binding must be created for channel factory error. Not sure why binding and endpoint is going null in this case.What  have i done is I created another C# project  and added the service reference in that and then copied the folder and pasted in my  xamarin.android project.Any idea why  this error is appearing ??

Answer (score 0):

To use your service in your app you have to creat a service client and put it in you project.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v5.0\Tools\SlSvcUtil has to be installed

you can download from:

Download & Install wenn noch nicht installiert:  https://www.microsoft.com/de-DE/download/details.aspx?id=28359

1. run "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v5.0\Tools\SlSvcUtil" http://celsius:8080/RWService ( with your service url and port)
   ( my sample service is a selfhosted service running on port 8080)
2. after successfully running it you have a .cs file
3. copy that file into your project and consume the service.

Comment: Thanks !!! But I already tried with slsvcUtil and it throws the exception that service is not compatible with  silverlight. I also raise the ticket for the same and I got a reply that its better to make some changes to the SOAP only.

Comment: is your service a public service hosted in the internet or a selhosted one? for my services it works perfect. Does the wcf testclient get answers?

Comment: yep !!! Its using some transport binding along with Soap header in and soap header out which has certain limitations with Mono as mono support only basic httpbinding.I need to modify the Soap service to make it work.